# Disable onclick function on image tag

Tags: jquery

jQuery how can I disable a click on `<img>` tag

```
$("#ico_cal_id").attr('disabled', 'disabled') or
$("#img_id").attr('disabled', 'disabled') is not working
```

Below is my code:

```
<span id="img_id"><src="ico_calendar.png" id="ico_cal_id" style="cursor: pointer"; onlick="showCalendar(this,'startDay','startMonth','startYear');" /></span>
```

whenever I click on the calendar_image the calendar is popping up

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
$("#ico_cal_id").prop("onclick", false);
```

More about `prop()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: This looks interesting, the first time I see something like that. Is it a good practice to reset it like this?

Comment: @dotweb: Yes. In jQuery, at least.

Answer (score 2):

`img` elements do not have a `disabled` attribute, so setting it won't affect its behaviour.

You could prevent the event from bubbling and from executing other handlers with [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)...

```
$("#ico_cal_id").click(function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `$("#ico_cal_id").removeAttr("onclick")` if the event is always being attached inline.

Comment: What is the difference between `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`?

Comment: `preventDefault()` prevents the default action of the element while `stopPropagation()` prevents it from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Comment: @JakeFeasel `preventDefault()` prevents the default browser behaviour, and `stopPropagation()` prevents events from bubbling to ancestors.

Comment: Cool thanks.  I particularly like your updated answer - that's a good one to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the onclick property?

```
$("#ico_cal_id")[0].onclick = null;
```

or:

```
$("#ico_cal_id").removeAttr("onclick");
```

Comment: $("#ico_cal_id")[0].onclick = null; is working for me, if I want to enable onclick again how can I do that?  Thanks

Comment: $("#ico_cal_id").removeAttr("onclick"); also works fine, how can I add the attribute back.

Answer (score 0):

These answers didn't work for me as I had unobtrusive jquery that bypassed that inline js function call.

I do not like "hack" code but for this image issue I did this

**HTML code**

```
<input type="hidden" id="responseMode"/>
```

**Code When to disable**

```
$("#responseMode").val("response");
```

**jquery img click**

```
$("#myImageID").click(function() {
    if ($("#responseMode").val() === "response") {
        // ??
     } else {
        workedModalCall();
     }

});
```

Otherwise ALL of the other answered still allowed for my jquery click function to run and then the modal function call I didn't want to be called happened workedModalCall();